# Moving a Django Foreign Key to another model while preserving data?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application where I have a basic user model and user profile model.

```py
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    offices = models.ManyToManyField(Office)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Each user has a profile and can be assigned to many different offices.

What I am looking to do is have it so that a User can have many profiles, but the profiles can be assigned to different offices.

At the moment, this isn't possible as the Office field is assigned at the User level and not the Profile level. I envision 2 ways to solve this:

1. Find some way to move the `offices` field over to the Profile field.
2. Create a new model something along the lines of `ProfileNoUser` that has a foreign key to the user model as well as have an `offices` foreign key within it.

Which option do you think is best? If #1, how can I do that?

Comment: So a `User` can have one `Profile` per `Office`? It is thus the "intermediate" table in the m2m relation?

Comment: At the moment, a `User` can be part of many `Office`, but can only have 1 profile. What I am trying to achieve is have a User control many profiles, but those profiles are assigned to many offices. Is that a bit more clear? The reasoning is to have the User managing their entire family, but each family member can be at a different office. Let me know if you need some more clarification. Thanks for the comment @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your question about [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)?

If so you should read the linked documentation.

It is indeed your first proposal that is the best in my opinion.

Here's how to do it.

## Step 1: make the changes to the model

You change your model to match your target:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offices = models.ManyToManyField(Office)
```

Run `makemigrations`:

```
(.venv) ~/c/s/m/mysite> ./manage.py makemigrations 
Migrations for 'so':
  so/migrations/0002_auto_20200825_1311.py
    - Remove field offices from user
    - Add field offices to profile
```

## Step 2: edit the migration file to migrate existing data

Open the file created the previous step. It will look something like:

```py
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-08-25 13:11

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('so', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='offices',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='offices',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='so.Office'),
        ),
    ]
```

You need to do two things here:

- You can see that with the order generated by Django it will **first** remove the old FK and **then** add the new one. You should change that so it is the other way around.
- Then you will have to write some python code that the migration will execute at *the right time*

*The right time* is just after the new FK has been created and before the old one gets deleted so you have access to both to migrate data:

```py
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-08-25 13:11

from django.db import migrations, models

def migrate_office_to_profile(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('so', 'User')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        for office in user.office_set:
            user.profile.add(office)

def migrate_office_to_user(apps, schema_editor):
    Profile = apps.get_model('so', 'Profile')
    for profile in Profile.objects.all():
        profile.user.add(profile.offices)
        for office in profile.office_set:
            profile.user.add(office)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('so', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='offices',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='so.Office'),
        ),
        # This is where your python code will be called
        migrations.RunPython(
            # This is called in the forward migration
            migrate_office_to_profile,
            # This is called in the backward migration
            reverse_code=migrate_office_to_user
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='offices',
        ),
    ]
```

***I haven't tested this on real data. This is your part.***

## Step 3: run and debug your migration

Make a copy of your database, run the migration and see how it does:

```
(.venv) ~/c/s/m/mysite> ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, so
Running migrations:
  Applying so.0002_auto_20200825_1311... OK
```

When dealing with data migration you should **always** write and debug the reverse migration:

```
(.venv) ~/c/s/m/mysite> ./manage.py migrate so 0001
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0001_initial, from so
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying so.0002_auto_20200825_1311... OK
```

Remember that migration files are **added to version control** and part of your software.

**=== EDIT ===**

Clarifying the idea of *reverse* or *backwards* migration.

Your Django migrations are usually run only one way: going up the migration numbers.

But for all the testing and careful thinking that you might apply during development, you can't always account for **production data**. The code is "easy" because it's the same in production as it is on your dev server. But the production data is usually different.

It can happen that a Django migration fails during deployment. For example, because you are adding an explicit unique constraint that you thought could only be true. But somehow with production data the migration will raise an integrity error.

You are then stuck with a half finished migration and new code that cannot run without the migration. If you took the time to make sure your migration can be run foward **and** backward without loss of data, you can safely undo the migration and revert back to the previous code and go back to figure out what went wrong, instead of having to fix it on the spot.

The forward and backward migration are automatically handled by Django for the model structure, but for data migration you have to write the functions given to `migrations.RunPython`.

Comment: Appreciate the very thorough answer, really helps! When you say i should always write and debug the reverse migration, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I detailed a bit more this part in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there some documentation with further reading on the forward/backwards migrations?

Comment: There is some information in Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#runpython otherwise it's mostly experience on my part. Don't hesitate to share if you find something.